# Two host only networks do not see each other. Why?

Tags: virtualbox

I need to build a lab with particulatly following params:

- 1 VM uses host only adapter vboxnet0 (subnet is .56.0/24).
- 1 VM uses
  host only adapter vboxnet1 (subnet is .57.0/24).

Host OS is Linux Mint.
HyperVisor - VirtualBox.
Rotung table on the host:

```
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp4s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.56.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
192.168.57.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet1
```

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is set to 1 (enabled)

iptables:
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

So the issue is that both VMs can only ping its gateway integface. but cannot reach each other. What i am missing?

Comment: i also somehow managed to forward icmp from one subnet to another:

`tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on vboxnet1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:53:42.946774 IP 192.168.57.100 > 192.168.56.20: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 17920, length 40` but reply is lost ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much on network and ip, but to me i see 192.168.56.0 will only be able to see 192.168.57.0 if the subnet mask is 255.255.0.0  otherwise they are different networks